# Plot won't fit in R window

Tags: r, graphics, plot, statistics, image-resizing

I am using the `meta` package in R to do a meta-analysis of proportions. I have about a hundred studies in my analysis. When I type `forest(result)` to create my forest plot, it works, but the graphic is chopped off at the top and bottom. It won't fit in the plot window no matter what I do! I am stumped on how to solve this. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Save it out to a PDF or PNG file.

Comment: Any idea how to do that? I tried typing `png(filename = "test.png")` but it still cuts off the image (see above).

Comment: have you tried `pdf(filename="test.pdf",width=20,height=8)` (extreme but should give you the idea)?

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I usually right click on the graphic and copy it as a meta-file, then paste that into PowerPoint, where I can ungroup it and play around with the pieces. Is there a way to do that like this?

Comment: try `win.metafile(filename="test.wmf",width=20,height=8)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found setting the margins to be the easiest solution.

For those that encounter the same, read more here: https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/plot-margins.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33916261)