# Saving a plot in R from forest.robu function that does not fit plot window

Tags: r, plot, graphics

Using the forest.robu function from the `robumeta` package. Trying  `pdf(filename="test.pdf",width=20,height=8)` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134771/plot-wont-fit-in-r-window) did result in the error "unused argument filename". Any idea how I could make a plot from this function that does not fit the plot window fit in an output file? Thank you!
[image: output plot image]

Comment: As the error message says, `pdf()` has no argument called `filename`. Have you tried `pdf(file="test.pdf",width=20,height=8)`?

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the description of the function, but using pdf(file="test.pdf",width=20,height=8) results in a pdf file that is not readable. Could it be related to the issue that I don't seem to feed the object (plot) to the pdf?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you don't yet understand how R graphics devices are used. One needs to set a particular output device up and then `print` to it with one of the three graphics paradigms and then execute `dev.off()` to finish the process. Failing to execute dev.off() with ps or pdf or png will start a file but then it doesn't get finish and will be unreadable. I'm guessing that `forest.robu` constructs an object using either ggplot or lattice function calls, so do this:

```
?pdf; ?Devices; ?pdf.options  # the help pages have further useful links 

pdf(file= "My_grph.pdf", width=20, height=8)
gobj <- forest.robu( ..... whatever ...)
print(gobj)
dev.off()
```

If on the other hand, `forest.robu()` uses base-graphics plotting, then the `print` call is unneeded and might even cause problems so leave it out.

Comment: Great, yes, I had not understood how the R graphics devices work, but do now. Thank you for your help.